# Como eu boto uma classe para funcionar diante de uma condição usando ngclass

Tags: html, css, angular

Eu estou escrevendo um código em angular e estou tentando fazer uma situação em que, ao escolher o nome de uma cidade, dependendo do tamanho dele, o tamanho do espaço que comporta o nome aumente dependendo do nome da cidade. Eu tentei fazer uma classe em css que só ativa quando a condição acontece mas fica dando erro e eu não sei porque. Aqui o trecho em angular:

```
<div [ngClass]="{city.length < 16 ? 'desktopCityFilterName' : 'desktopCityFilterName2'}">{{city}}
```

Aqui o css:

```
.desktopCityFilterName {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 115px;
}

.desktopCityFilterName2 {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 189px;
}
```

Em caso de eu tenha sido claro, o usuário escolhe uma cidade e o display aumenta o tamanho do espaço em que o nome é escrito caso o nome da cidade exceda 16 caracteres.

Ex: Aracajú menos que 16, logo width continua 115px

Campos do Jordão mais que 16, então width passa a ser 189px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema aí é que a diretiva [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), não funciona dessa forma como um **ngIf** por exemplo, que pode ser passada uma condição **`ternária`**, essa diretiva funciona de outra forma.

Para o que deseja fazer, que é setar uma classe na `div` conforme o tamanho da string, a maneira correta (não sei se a única) é declarar a **classe** e logo passar a condição após o símbolo **`:`** separando as classes por um sinal de **`,`** e inserindo a outra classe com a outra condição:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'desktopCityFilterName': city.length < 16, 'desktopCityFilterName2': city.length > 16}"> {{city}} </div>
```

**Pode ver um exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-class-stack).**